# Running native Delphi code in dot net environment with c sharp

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, delphi, plsql

I have a Delphi program consisting of mostly Visual Interface(Buttons, TextBoxes etc.) and a little bit business logic.

The business logic is mostly included in `Pl-Sql` of `Oracle Database` running by Delphi.
I want to carry the project in Delphi to C Sharp but i want to do this part by part.

What i think is to create a C Sharp project in Visual Studio and to run it with Delphi code(including Visual Interfaces) and part by part replace the code and the Visual Interface in Delphi with C Sharp.

Is it possible?

Comment: You really need to define and elaborate on what it is you are exactly looking to achieve; are you looking to convert an existing delphi application to C# or merely execute the delphi application from a C# application?

Comment: You really should look through the answers to [Migrating a Delphi 7 application to .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207169/migrating-a-delphi-7-application-to-net).  No matter what versions of Delphi (well, win32/VCL Delphi at any rate) or VS you're dealing with, the answers are going to be the same.

Comment: I want to convert the Delphi application to C Sharp but it's hard to achieve in a short time and i don't have time to run simultaneous projects one in Delphi and one in C Sharp. So i think it will be feasible to run the Delphi code in .net and replacing Delphi code with C Sharp code module by module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remobjects Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/) seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Mixing Delphi and C# GUI in the same application is possible, but hard to achieve. You'll need to set up a whole infrastructure to organise interop between the two languages. You'll end up creating a huge amount of interop code that you will subsequently abandon. Even worse, the interop code will need to be two way. You'll sometimes have C# visual code talking to Delphi non-visual. And vice-versa. The idea of converting the code module by module sounds good, but I predict it will entail vast amounts of interop scaffolding.

It would be easier to slice it along the visual/non-visual divide, but that's not what you are proposing. So frankly I think your current plan is far from optimal. I would not entertain it. I think a clean port is the best option.